# MS Exchange fire external programme

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server

I have a client that wants to email images to a specific email address 1 at a time. When the email comes in I want to resize the image and do some other stuff with it preferably using a programme I have wrote in c#.

Can anyone tell me, or point me in the right direction to get this to work

thanks

Comment: the final application where the image is going to is an asp.net web site

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Outlook PIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx)
and particularly the Items collection events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.items_events.aspx)

Once you setup your Outlook profile(hope you can use Outlook) you will subscribe to the ItemAdd event of the Items collection of your Inbox folder - there(in its event handler) you resize your picture and do whatever you want with it.